# Is it possible to load Google banner ads from an AsyncTask or background thread in lists?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, ads

I have done a search for smooth loading of Google banner Ads in ListView/RecyclerViews, and the best answer I can find is to try and [use "runOnUiThread"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17307300/loading-ad-admob-on-background-thread) to load the ad, which still results in laggy performance. AdView seems to only offer [loadAd()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdView) which runs it's own background task under the hood, but still results in performance issues.

Is there a way to load banner ads with similar efficiency to Picasso or Glide can with images ? If you have a solution please provide a simple example that demonstrates smooth scroll in a listview.

Answer (score 1):

NOT POSSIBLE.

you have to load it on UI Thread.

Comment: Why is it not possible? Please clarify

Comment: google has given his own ads sdk. and it has its own standards. we can't modify

Comment: You should put this in your answer. Explaining your answers will help readers in the future who happen upon this question.